# Fragment replaced by another Fragment in an Activity, how to navigate?

Tags: android, android-fragments, architecture, navigation-drawer

I'm using a NavigationDrawer and one Activity where I'm replacing Fragments within the FrameLayout. Navigating through NavigationDrawer and replacing Fragments inside of the Activity is straightforward. I'm not sure how to handle when I replace a Fragment from another Fragment. Example:

I show a Fragment which is a basic List, and when the user clicks on one of the items, I show a new Fragment. Now, from this new Fragment, I may choose to show another Fragment, which results in a deeper Fragment hierarchy. I know that I can navigate through with 
`.addToBackStack()` and in the case of Back button, call

```
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

from the Activity, but as deeper the Fragment hierarchy gets, the more complicated and dirty it becomes. Is there a good article, or architectural approach to handle a case like this one?

Comment: you want to replace or also want track the stack of the fragment

Comment: if you want handle back press then you have to keep fragment in stack by add fragment if not then use replace also use fragment addtobackstack true or false based on your condition.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario you should use *Nested Fragments*.
You can embed fragments inside fragments.

To nest a fragment, simply call `getChildFragmentManager()` on the `Fragment` in which you want to add a fragment. This returns a `FragmentManager` that you can use like you normally do from the top-level activity to create fragment transactions. For example, here’s some code that adds a fragment from within an existing `Fragment` class:

```
Fragment videoFragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.video_fragment, videoFragment).commit();
```

From within a nested fragment, you can get a reference to the parent fragment by calling `getParentFragment().` And then your parent backstack and child backstack will be separated.

This is how to do it right. The other question is maybe you should consider using `intent` and new activity instead of 10 nested fragments? Here is an article about child fragments.[link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-working-with-androids-child-fragment-manager-and-custom-transitions/)
 [Stack similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901409/is-nesting-fragments-in-android-bad)

Answer (score 0):

Make Fragments tags in your Main Activity:

```
 //----------------Fragment TAGS-----------------------\\
    private final String FRAGMENT_BOOK_RIDE = "Frag Book Ride";
    private final String FRAGMENT_RIDE_HISTORY = "Frag Ride History";
    private final String FRAGMENT_PAYMENT = "Frag Payment";
    private final String FRAGMENT_PROFILES_SETTINGS = "Frag Profile & Settings";
    private final String FRAGMENT_HELP = "Frag Help";
    //-----------------------------------------------------\\
```

Navigation item selection:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here. \\
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_book_ride:
                removeAllFragments();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container_fl, new BookRideFragment(getApplicationContext())
                                , FRAGMENT_BOOK_RIDE)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_ride_history:
                removeAllFragments();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container_fl, new RideHistoryFragment(getApplicationContext())
                                , FRAGMENT_RIDE_HISTORY)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_payment:
                removeAllFragments();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container_fl, new PaymentFragment(getApplicationContext())
                                , FRAGMENT_PAYMENT)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                removeAllFragments();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container_fl, new ProfileSettingFragment(getApplicationContext())
                                , FRAGMENT_PROFILES_SETTINGS)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_help:
                removeAllFragments();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container_fl, new HelpFragment(getApplicationContext())
                                , FRAGMENT_HELP)
                        .commit();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Handling backKey press:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            backKeyMethods();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom back key method for managing fragment back key behavior
     */
    private void backKeyMethods() {
        RideHistoryFragment rideHistoryFragment = (RideHistoryFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_RIDE_HISTORY);
        PaymentFragment paymentFragment = (PaymentFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_PAYMENT);
        HelpFragment helpFragment = (HelpFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_HELP);
        ProfileSettingFragment userProfileFragment = (ProfileSettingFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_PROFILES_SETTINGS);

        if (rideHistoryFragment != null && rideHistoryFragment.isVisible()) {
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_book_ride);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container_fl, new BookRideFragment(getApplicationContext())
                            , FRAGMENT_BOOK_RIDE)
                    .commit();
        } else if (paymentFragment != null && paymentFragment.isVisible()) {
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_book_ride);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container_fl, new BookRideFragment(getApplicationContext())
                            , FRAGMENT_BOOK_RIDE)
                    .commit();
        } else if (userProfileFragment != null && userProfileFragment.isVisible()) {
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_book_ride);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container_fl, new BookRideFragment(getApplicationContext())
                            , FRAGMENT_BOOK_RIDE)
                    .commit();
        } else if (helpFragment != null && helpFragment.isVisible()) {
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_book_ride);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container_fl, new BookRideFragment(getApplicationContext())
                            , FRAGMENT_BOOK_RIDE)
                    .commit();
        } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove all fragments in Fragment BackStack
     */
    private void removeAllFragments() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

Use addToBackStack(null) whenever you want to go deep, so when you will press backKey it will pop immediate fragment.
Hope it helps.